# removeChild with PHP DOM doesn't work

Tags: php, domdocument, removechild, dom-node

I have the following code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($quiz['value']);
$imageElement = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
}
if(is_object($imageElement)){ 
    $image = $imageElement->getAttribute('src');
    $imageElement->parentNode->removeChild($imageElement); 
}else{ 
    $image = '#'; 
}
$quiz['value'] = $doc->saveHTML();
```

However, I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function removeChild() on a non-object.

The loaded dom string may or may not contain an img element.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: well, the error message is obvious. Your `$imageElement->parentNode` is not an object. Make sure it is and the error will go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_object()` isn't a good test for this, as `->item()` will return an object no matter what. It just won't be a DOMNode if there isn't an actual matching item in the DOMNodeList that the getElementsByTagName returns.

A better method would be:

```
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
if ($images->length > 0) {
   $imgnode = $images->item(0);
   $image = $imgnode->getAttribute('src');
   $imgnode->parentNode->removeChild($imgnode); 
} else {
   $image = '#';
}
```

Comment: [From the manual on `DOMNodeList::item()` on Return Values:](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) *The node at the indexth position in the DOMNodeList, or NULL if that is not a valid index* - also see http://codepad.viper-7.com/gaXVsf